# Spring WebFlux Netty SSL with Self Signed Certificate error

Tags: ssl, netty, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I'm trying to access my Spring Boot application running on Netty via https in localhost, using a self signed certificate on server side.

My `application.properties` looks like this:

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=test.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=testkey
```

I've generated the keystore via:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias testkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -keystore test.jks -validity 36500
```

I'm getting the following error:

> io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:472)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)

I tried to import the certificate to the JDK truststore, even to the OS but still the same. One source suggested to name the key alias as "testkey" to make it work, which didn't work either. Since there are no other mentions of this error in Google, I'm hoping you could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve by generating a locally valid cert with https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

Comment: Looks like Netty is verifying the SAN (Subject Alternate Name) in the self signed certs. Adding localhost, 127.0.0.1 to SAN made this error go away when localhost client connects to the server using HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Peter answer -

Download mkcert release from https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert/releases or build directly from source.

On Windows to generate self-signed cert in p12 format -

`mkcert-v1.4.1-windows-amd64.exe -pkcs12 -p12-file self-signed-cert.p12 localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1`

And add following configuration to Spring Boots properties file -

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:self-signed-cert.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
server.ssl.key-password=changeit
```

Note - `classpath` if you are adding `self-signed-cert.p12` in `resources` folder. If you want to run it from a specific location `server.ssl.key-store=./self-signed-cert.p12`

Answer (score 0):

This `server.ssl.key-store=test.jks` specifies that your `test.jks` is located in the root folder of your project, so check whether it is really there.

If you have this file somewhere else in the class path, you can use `classpath` scheme in order to specify the location of the file i.e.`server.ssl.key-store=classpath:<path-to-the-file>/test.jks`

[Check this for more info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-configure-ssl)

Comment: If Spring can't find the keystore you get an exception: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store`

Comment: This issue is Netty + WebFlux specific, it worked with Tomcat + MVC.